# SQL to Return Dates for Selected Week Only

Tags: sql, date

I'm writing a SQL query on a timesheet report. I need the report to return only the details for the week of the selected date.

E.g., if I pick 02/01/2012 (dd/MM/yyyy), then it should only return results between 02/01/2012 and 08/01/2012.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean a calendar week?  (If you specify a Wednesday, the calculation includes the previous Monday to the following Sunday, for example?)  Or just the 7 days starting with the specified date?

Comment: Whatever day the user picks plus 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  dateField >= @yourDate
  AND dateField < @yourDate + 7
```

Some variations of SQL may have specific ways of adding 7 days to a datevalue.  Such as...
- `DateAdd(Day, 7, @date)`
- `DATE_ADD(@date, INTERVAL 7 DAYS)`
- etc, etc

This option is both index friendly, and is resilient to database fields that have time parts as well as date parts.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE date BETWEEN '1/02/2012' AND '1/08/2012';
```

you can replace the example date with your date and yourdate + 6.

Look here for example: http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sql-between-datetime.shtml

Comment: When using `BETWEEN` this should be +6, not +7.

Comment: You're right of course. I'm used to using timestamps :( - applies to me too

Answer (score 0):

You easiest is the equivalent of [WEEK_OF_YEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekofyear) function in your SQL engine

But you can also use DATE_ADD

```
WHERE table.date BETWEEN target_date AND DATE_ADD(target_date,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: When using BETWEEN this should be `6 DAY` and not `7 DAY`

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the database system you're using. MySQL has a function calles WEEK(), SQL Server can do something like this with the DATEPART() function:

MySQL:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM table
WHERE WEEK(date_col) = WEEK('02/01/2012');
```

SQL SERVER:

```
   SELECT 
    * 
    FROM table
    WHERE DATEPART(WEEK, datecol) = DATEPART(WEEK,'02/01/2012');
```

Comment: This obfuscates INDEXes and results in a scan rather than a seek.

Comment: That is so, but adding adding seven days to an arbitrary date as in your post (Dems), may not necessary result in having the days of a single week (we.g. wednesday of last week to wednesday of this week). You may be fast, but correct????

Comment: Ahhh, I get you! It does depend if the OP wants a calendar week or not, and what the OP considers the week start day.  I just assumed a 7 day window, now I simply am not certain which the OP wants :)  Good point!